# R: If x=condition, replace x and next 2 values by mean of x-1 and x+3

Tags: r, indexing, replace, mean, sapply

I have an input like this:

`input=c(8,-200,4,0,9,5,-900,10,8,8)`

and I want to do the following:

If input<(-100)
replace input and next two values by the mean of the value before and after the values replaced

So that the result should look like this:

```
result=c(8,8.5,8.5,8.5,9,5,6.5,6.5,6.5,8)

df=data.frame(input, result)
```

I tried the following which only works if I have only one case in my df:

```
ind <- which(df$input<(-100))
df$input[ind:ind+2] <- sapply(ind, function(i) with(df, mean(c(input[i-1], input[i+3]))))
```

For more then one case I get the error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In ind:ind : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
2: In ind:ind : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
3: In df$input[ind:ind + 2] <- sapply(ind, function(i) with(df, mean(c(input[i -  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I might also have the case where the value x+3 is another value to be replaced:

```
input2=c(1,1,2,-100,7,0,-200,4,5,6)
```

In which case I want to skip over the value again and take the next x+3 value (here: the average of 2 and 6) so that:

```
result2=c(1,1,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,6)
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: If your condition is `input < -100` then in `input2` there is only one value to replace, since `-100` does not match the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution :

```
myfun <- function(input){

  # Replace values by NA
  ind <- which(input < -100)
  ind <- unique(c(ind, ind+1, ind+2))
  ind <- ind[ind<=length(input)]
  input[ind] <- NA

  # Replace NA by mean
  input[ind] <- rowMeans(cbind(na.locf(input, fromLast = T, na.rm = F),
                               na.locf(input, fromLast = F, na.rm = F)), 
                         na.rm = T)[ind]

  input
}

myfun(c(8,8.5,8.5,8.5,9,5,6.5,6.5,6.5,8))
# [1] 8.0 8.5 8.5 8.5 9.0 5.0 6.5 6.5 6.5 8.0
myfun(c(1,1,2,-200,7,0,-200,4,5,6))
# [1] 1 1 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 6
```